# How to exclude items from another list of different type?

Tags: c#

I have a List of type object (Roles) which has the following values: username, rolename.

The list retrieves all data using the code below:
    var listOfUsers = GetAllUsers();

Now I have a list of type string:

```
List<string> excludedUsers = new List<string>();
excludedUsers.Add("johndoe");
```

I want to exclude all users from the list excludedUsers. I am not sure how to exclude this list.

```
var finalList = listOfUsers.Where(x => x.DisplayName != "john").ToList();
```

Comment: `Where(x => !excludedUsers.Contains(x.DisplayName))`?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like

`var finalList = listOfUsers.Where(x => !excludedUsers.Contains(x.DisplayName)).ToList();`